# How to add CircularProgressIndicator using flutter_bloc

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am trying to make that when I submit the button, the isLoading variable is set to true, and when the block issues the state it returns to false, to show a circular progress indicator.
My problem is that I don't know WHERE or HOW to put that variable, nor how to tell the bloc that this variable is true before / outside the BlocBuilder,

this is the code of my button:

```
TextButton(
                  child: Text("submit"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    
                    context
                        .read<ShowMusicHomeBloc>()
                        .add(OnSearchTracks(q: _searchText.text));

                    
                    _searchText.clear();
                  },
                ),
```

Could you give me a practical example how I can set this variable isLoading to true using flutter_bloc?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `LoadingState` and emit it when you press the button.

```
abstract class MyState {}

class MyLoadingState extends MyState {}

class MyLoadedState extends MyState {
  final MyData data;
  MyLoadedState(this.data);
}

// other states like ErrorState or InitialState

class MyCubit extends Cubit<MyState>{
  MyCubit(this.someService) : super(MyLoadingState());

  final SomeService someService;

  Future<void> fetchData(){
    emit(MyLoadingState);
    
    final fetchedData = someService.fetchData();
    emit(MyLoadedState(fetchedData));
  }
}
```

you can apply the same concept to `Bloc`s too.